# Vulkan 1.1, SPIR-V 1.3, libshaderc, validation layers error

Tags: vulkan

I am using libshaderc to compile at runtime Shader codes. I do not have any issue when I compile them. If I compile them to Vulkan 1.0 (`shaderc_env_version_vulkan_1_0`) I do not have any error with validation, however, when I am using Vulkan 1.1 (`shaderc_env_version_vulkan_1_1`) as target environment, I get this validation error `SPIR-V module not valid: Invalid SPIR-V binary version 1.3 for target environment SPIR-V 1.0 (under Vulkan 1.0 semantics)`

I am using the SDK 1.1.97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation layers use the API version you're targeting to validate your SPIR-V modules against. So if you use set `VkApplicatinInfo::apiVersion` to `VK_API_VERSION_1_0` (or don't provide a `VkApplicationInfo`, since the default is 1.0), then validation will check that what you're using is valid under 1.0, even if the device supports 1.1. Since Vulkan 1.0 didn't support SPIR-V 1.3 modules, you'll get that error.

Comment: I gave*. I will update my question with some code if you want

Comment: Does your device support Vulkan 1.1 (VkPhysicalDeviceProperties::apiVersion)? Even if you ask for version 1.1, if you're running on a 1.0 device you'll still be validated against that.

Comment: Okay, my drivers were not properly installed, I dont know why, but now it works, thanks ;)